# Matplotlib: After setting the xticks, the label of x-axis disappears

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

[image]

The picture is shown above.

As you can see, the label of x-axis disappear.

The code used to draw this picture is shown below:

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(1,1)
stock_num_everyday_df.plot(ax=ax3, title='XXXXX')
plt.xticks(pd.date_range('2009-01-01','2020-05-01',freq='Y'))
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add `plt.tight_layout()` at the end (but before `plt.show()`) ?

Comment: @JohanC I tried but it was the same..

Comment: Consider creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help you find out what's going wrong.